How to control the order of scenarios execution when running in parallel mode - Cucumber Junit5
I have the below use case. I have multiple feature files each feature file consists of scenarios as listed below.
Feature1:
@capture
Scenario C1:
@capture
Scenario C2:
.
.
.
@capture
Scenario Cn:
@batchJob
Scenario B1:
@validation
Scenario V1:
@validation
Scenario V2:
.
.
.
@validation
Scenario V3:
I have a dependency that @batchJob has to execute after all @captures are done and @validation should execute @batchjob is done. I have handled it in the Hooks and they work fine.
However, when running in parallel, I see that scenarios are assigned to threads. So I want to understand in what order the scenarios get assigned to thread. What I have observed, every time the last scenario of each feature file is getting started, so 10 threads popped up and assigned to @validation scenarios only as each file's last scenario is tagged with that (which will be held in indefinite state because of my dependency, as I don't have other threads to run for @capture scenarios).
So I'm trying to understand what is the default order of the scenarios execution.
Is there any way to control the order either by pom.xml using profiles or some other method?
here are the dependencies I am using
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>7.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
        <version>7.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.6</version>
    </dependency>

And this is what I have in junit-platform.properties file
"cucumber.execution.parallel.enabled=true"

The basic recommendation is to run the mvn commands for each tags separately. But I want to get these tags executed in order during "mvn clean install" itself. So I came across profiles that to be added to pom.xml and use maven antrun plugin to execute the phases. However, it is not working.

You can use @IncludeTags on your @Suite annotated class. Then have multiple suites and let Surefire order them. Or declare a suite that selects your other suites in order. Have a look at https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.10.1/api/org.junit.platform.suite.api/org/junit/platform/suite/api/package-summary.html

Thanks for the reply.. I already used the same approach. However Surefire is ordering them randomly. I need desired order to be executed.

Looks like we can control using the below configuration in maven-surefire plugin

alphabetical

Yes! Well done!
